# Part of XCode Instruments UI - available as IB plugin?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, user-interface, interface-builder

on top of Instruments window, there is nice control component, which shows timer and count of runs, or in top of XCode window the same control shows messages releated to build&run of current project.

[image] [image]

Is this control available as IB plugin or can it be easily reproduced?
I know I can use NSView and style it, add controls and subviews, but it would be nice component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not publicly available components. So you'll need to build them yourself.